# If I have a function take multiple parameters, but I have only a list, how to pass it to the fucntion?

Tags: scala

```
def fun1(a:String,b:String){
}
```

and I have a

```
val aList=List("1","2")
```

How could I call fun1 using aList?

Comment: This topic has already been covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170646/spread-parameters-in-scala), it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with repeated parameters:

```
def fun1(a: String*){}

val args: = List("1","2","3")
fun1(args: _*)
```

Or this:

```
def fun1(a: String, b: String){}
val args: = List("1", "2")
fun1(args(0), args(1))
```