# Function with any number of arguments as parameter

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have method eval which takes List of Function and arguments, currently I am writing case for every possible function. How can I write it more generic?

```
implicit class Expression(p: Product) {
  def eval = p.productIterator.toList match {
    case (f: ((Any) => Any)) :: p1 :: Nil => f(p1)
    case (f: ((Any, Any) => Any)) :: p1 :: p2 :: Nil => f(p1, p2)
    case (f: ((Any, Any, Any) => Any)) :: p1 :: p2 :: p3 :: Nil => f(p1, p2, p3)
  }
}
def print = (x: Any) => println(">> " + x)
def add = (x: Any, y: Any) => x.asInstanceOf[Int] + y.asInstanceOf[Int]
(print, "test").eval
(add, 2, 3).eval
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Spread' parameters in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170646/spread-parameters-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write something like this using shapeless, which has the benefit that it is type safe and checked at compile time (compared with using `Any` in your `Expression.eval`).

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist._
import syntax.std.function._
import ops.function._

def eval[P <: Product, G <: HList, F, L <: HList, R](
  p: P
)(implicit 
  gen: Generic.Aux[P, G], 
  ihc: IsHCons.Aux[G, F, L], 
  ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => R]
) = { 
  val l = gen.to(p)
  val (func, args) = (l.head, l.tail)
  func.toProduct(args)
}
```

Which you could use as :

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
val stringLength: String => Int = _.length

eval((add _, 1, 2))             // Int = 3
eval((stringLength, "foobar"))  // Int = 6
eval((stringLength, 4))         // does not compile
```

You can also use it with a case class if it follows the same format (first a function then the right arguments for that function) :

```
case class Operation(f: (Int, Int) => Int, a: Int, b: Int)
eval(Operation(_ + _, 1, 2))    // Int = 3
eval(Operation(_ * _, 1, 2))    // Int = 2
```

Comment: Could you show me also a way to implement it without shapeless and type safety, I am just really curious is it possible to do it in simpler way?

Comment: Generic programming like this with abstraction over function arity and the argument types is not possible in Scala without shapeless.

Comment: Is there a way to constrain the possible arguments, for example, only allow `Option[_]`?