# How can I make function for unspecified number of arguments function In Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to make some function for unspecified number of arguments of function

for example

```
scala> def test(fx: (String*) => Boolean, arg: String*): Boolean = fx(arg: _*)
test: (fx: String* => Boolean, arg: String*)Boolean

scala> def AA(arg1: String, arg2: String) :Boolean = {
       println ("Arg1 : " + arg1 + " Arg2 : " + arg2)
       true}
AA: (arg1: String, arg2: String)Boolean

scala> test(AA,"ASDF","BBBB")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String) => Boolean
 required: String* => Boolean
            test(AA,"ASDF","BBBB")
                  ^
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: There are ways to solve this, but you do realize that it will mean that you can have errors at **runtime** when passing in `args` a different numbers of  values that `fx` expects? Is that OK with you?

Comment: Also, can you be more specific on exactly what you are attempting to achieve? As it stands, your `test` method does nothing more than calling the passed function so it's hard to guess why you cannot directly call the function in the first place (and thus hard to propose any potentially saner alternative)

Answer (score 3):

This could be done using shapeless with `ProductArgs` and something similar to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33304323/5020846) to another question.

```
import shapeless.{HList, ProductArgs}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons
import shapeless.ops.function.FnToProduct
import shapeless.syntax.std.function._

object test extends ProductArgs {
  def applyProduct[L <: HList, NarrowArgs <: HList, Args <: HList, F, R](
    l: L
  )(implicit 
    ihc: IsHCons.Aux[L, F, NarrowArgs],
    ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, Args => R],
    ev: NarrowArgs <:< Args
  ): R = {
    val (func, args) = (l.head, l.tail)
    func.toProduct(args)
  }
}
```

Which you can use as :

```
def aa(s1: String) = s1.length
def bb(s1: String, s2: String) = s1 * s2.length

test(aa _, "foo")         // Int = 3
test(bb _, "foo", "bar")  // String = foofoofoo
// test(aa _, "foo", "bar") doesn't compile
```

Extending `ProductArgs` transforms or `test(aa _, "foo")` (which is actually `test.apply(aa _, "foo")`) to `test.applyProduct((aa _) :: "foo" :: HNil)`. In `applyProduct` we check that the `HList` consists of a function and valid arguments.

---

*We shouldn't need the `NarrowArgs <:< Args`, but [`ProductArgs`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlists.scala#L174) seems to give the same result as [`SingletonProductArgs`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlists.scala#L197).*

Comment: That's nice, but it makes the explicit assumption that the function arity (in fact, even the exact signature) is fully know when calling `test` (or - admittedly- that we are OK to pass around shapeless type class instances along with the function, to make the call compile). And if that's the case, then what does  `test` bring to the table besides directly calling said function (or passing a thunk to `test` that does it). I think it would be more productive if OP explained what's his use case exactly.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles you are right, `test` is actually not really useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `AA` does not accept variable number of arguments, change it to:

```
def AA(args: String*) :Boolean
```

Comment: thanks. but I want to get all functions without reference to any number of parameters. 
if I have 2 functions like this `def AA (arg: String) = println(arg)` and `def BB(arg1: String, arg2: String) = println(arg1 + arg2)`, and I want to pass it to **test** function as a parameter. 
`test(AA,"HELLO")` and `test(BB,"HELLO","WORLD")`
is it possible??

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible.