# Achieving Ad hoc polymorphism at function parameter level (mixing parameters of different type)

Tags: scala, polymorphism, typeclass, implicit, scala-cats

When I have a function in Scala:

```scala
def toString[T: Show](xs: T*): String = paths.map(_.show).mkString
```

And the following type class instances in scope:

```scala
implicit val showA: Show[MyTypeA]
implicit val showB: Show[MyTypeB]
```

I can use function `toString` in the following ways:

```scala
val a1: MyTypeA
val a2: MyTypeA
val stringA = toString(a1, a2)

val b1: MyTypeB
val b2: MyTypeB
val stringB = toString(b1, b2)
```

But I cannot call `toString` mixing parameters of type `MyTypeA` and `MyTypeB`:

```scala
// doesn't compile, T is inferred to be of type Any
toString(a1, b1)
```

Is it possible to redefine `toString` in such a way that it becomes possible to mix parameters of different types (but only for which a `Show` typeclass is available)?

Note that I am aware of the cats show interpolator which solves this specific example, but I'm looking for a solution which can be applied to different cases as well (e.g. `toNumber`).

I am also aware of circumventing the problem by calling `.show` on the parameters before passing them to the `toString` function, but I'm looking for a way to avoid this as it results in code duplication.

Comment: Sadly no an easy one. I know that is possible using **Shapeless**, but it is quite complex. The other solution is the **magnet** pattern.

Comment: Related: [How can I make a function for unspecified number of arguments function In Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019127/how-can-i-make-function-for-unspecified-number-of-arguments-function-in-scala)

Comment: Indeed not easy it seems, though the answers show it is possible using shapeless. Ultimately I chose for calling `.show` on every argument before passing it, as it was least intrusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example with shapeless:

```
object myToString extends ProductArgs { //ProductArgs allows changing variable number of arguments to HList

    //polymorphic function to iterate over values of HList and change to a string using Show instances
    object showMapper extends Poly1 {

      implicit def caseShow[V](implicit show: Show[V]): Case.Aux[V, String] = {
        at[V](v => show.show(v))
      }

    }

    def applyProduct[ARepr <: HList](
        l: ARepr
    )(
        implicit mapper: Mapper[showMapper.type, ARepr]
    ): String = l.map(showMapper).mkString("", "", "")
}
```

Now let's test it:

```
case class Test1(value: String)
case class Test2(value: String)
case class Test3(value: String)

implicit val show1: Show[Test1] = Show.show(_.value)
implicit val show2: Show[Test2] = Show.show(_.value)

println(myToString(Test1("a"), Test2("b"))) //"ab"

println(myToString(Test1("a"), Test2("b"), Test3("c"))) //won't compile since there's no instance of Show for Test3
```

By the way, I think `toString` is not the best name, because probably it can cause weird conflicts with `toString` from `java.lang.Object`.

---

If you don't want to mess with shapeless, another solution that comes to my mind is to just create functions with different arity:

```
def toString[A: Show](a: A): String = ???
def toString[A: Show, B: Show](a: A, b: B): String = ???
//etc
```

It's definitely cumbersome, but it might be the easiest way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it in Dotty (note that most of the Dotty-specific features used here are not necessary; they're just to make life easier, but being able to abstract over tuples of different arities is something you can't do (easily) in Scala 2):

```scala
opaque type Show[T] = T => String
opaque type ShowTuple[T <: Tuple] = T => String
object ShowTuple {
  given ShowTuple[EmptyTuple] = _ => ""
  given showTuple[H, T <: Tuple](using show: Show[H], showTail: ShowTuple[T]) as ShowTuple[H *: T] = 
    { case h *: t => show(h) + "," + showTail(t) }
}

def multiToString[T <: Tuple](t: T)(using showTuple: ShowTuple[T]) =
  showTuple(t)
```

It can be used like this:

```
class TypeA(val i: Int)
class TypeB(val s: String)
class TypeC(val b: Boolean)

given Show[TypeA] = t => s"TypeA(${t.i})"
given Show[TypeB] = t => s"TypeB(${t.s})"
given Show[TypeC] = t => s"TypeC(${t.b})"

println(multiToString((new TypeA(10), new TypeB("foo"), new TypeC(true))))
```

Using a type for which an implicit is not given fails:

```
class TypeD

multiToString((new TypeA(10), new TypeB("foo"), new TypeC(true), new TypeD))
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KUBWHp5oR5K8iey91lFzvQ)

Answer (score 3):

What is the type of `paths`?

If it's `List[T]` then there should be an implicit `Show[T]` in scope.

If it's `List[Any]` then there should be an implicit `Show[Any]` in scope.

If `paths` contains elements of different types and `paths` is not a `List[Any]` then `paths` shouldn't be a `List[...]` at all. It can be of type `L <: HList`. You can try

```
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, Poly1, Poly2}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{LeftReducer, Mapper}

trait Show[T] {
  def show(t: T): String
}

implicit class ShowOps[T](t: T) {
  def show(implicit s: Show[T]): String = s.show(t)
}

object show extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[T: Show]: Case.Aux[T, String] = at(_.show)
}

object concat extends Poly2 {
  implicit def cse: Case.Aux[String, String, String] = at(_ + _)
}

def toString[L <: HList, L1 <: HList](xs: L)(implicit
  mapper: Mapper.Aux[show.type, L, L1],
  reducer: LeftReducer.Aux[L1, concat.type, String]
): String = xs.map(show).reduceLeft(concat)

type MyTypeA
type MyTypeB

implicit val showA: Show[MyTypeA] = ???
implicit val showB: Show[MyTypeB] = ???

val a1: MyTypeA = ???
val b1: MyTypeB = ???

toString(a1 :: b1 :: HNil)
```