# Scala equivalent to JavaScript array spread

Tags: java, scala

In JavaScript there is the nice [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_array_literals).

Example from MDN:

```
var parts = ['shoulders', 'knees']; 
var lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes']; 
// ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "and", "toes"]
```

Is there an equivalent in Scala?

Comment: Maybe this is of interest (more in the context of spreading over function parameters): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170646/spread-parameters-in-scala?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
val lyrics = Seq("head") ++ parts ++ Seq("and", "toes")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always `patch()`. It's arguments are a little more cryptic because it has a wider, more general, field of applications.

```
val parts = List("shoulders", "knees")
val lyrics = List("head", "and", "toes")

lyrics.patch(1, parts, 0)  // res0: List(head, shoulders, knees, and, toes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
val parts = List("shoulders", "knees")
val lyrics = "head" :: parts.::("and").::("knees")
```

However, this works only on `List` type

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no equivalent.

You can do like this.

```
val parts = Seq("shoulders", "knees"); 
val lyrics = "head" +: parts :+ "and" :+ "toes"
println(lyrics) // List(head, shoulders, knees, and, toes)
```